# Communication between MS Word and other process

Tags: windows, ms-word, jscript

I have a Word document open on my desktop. I want to be able to get information about the status of the Word document, say the doc url or content. What are the means to achieve it?

Currently, I'm using JScript. However the following line only gives a new instance of Word instead of the currently open Word doc.

```
var word = WScript.CreateObject("Word.Application");
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function to use is `GetObject()`. It will return a pointer to the first Word instance opened.

Comment: I have tried `var wordApp = WScript.GetObject("Word.Application");`, and I'm getting an error says that `Microsoft JScript runtime error: File name or class name not found during Automation operation`. What is the correct way of using this?

Comment: I'm not sure you need to specify Wscript - see [GetObject Function (Visual Studio - JScript)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebdktb00%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). Otherwise, this should work as you wrote it, assuming that you have an instance of Word open.

Comment: Apparently, this isn't supported by the WScript. One need to access it using Word Addin which will give more control on the current open MS Word doc. Thanks for the info still.